# how to give dynamic drop down and sub drop down by clicking button

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have one button called `add`,when you click add button one input field,one drop down  and one remove button will come,in that drop down if you select `test1` then sub dropdown will come like `test11,test12`,if you select `test2` from main drop down then sub drop down will change like `test21,test22`.

https://jsfiddle.net/xbf2vryc/

It is working fine in first row(in first input field and drop down),if I add one more input field,drop down and remove by click on `add` button then if I select drop down `test1` then I got sub drop down like `test11,test12`.

But here problem is first row sub drop down values also changing ,if I have 10 rows all those sub drop downs is changing,this is happening bez I am using class name,so is there any way to do this.

**Note :** One important thing is how to store this values is Mysqli database.